# How to parse date correctly java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z""?

Tags: java, date

I'm getting this date from bing search and have difficulty to parse it to date, I need
the time as well.

```
""2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z""
```

I'm doing this:

```
public static Date parseDate(String publishedDate) {
            
     String dateStr = publishedDate.replaceFirst("T", "");
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = null;
        if (publishedDate.length() > 10) {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss");         
        } else {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
          
     Date date = null;
     try {
            date = formatter.parse(publishedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return date;
    }
```

getting the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z""
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
```

Comment: why dont u use LocalDateTime.parse. I have tried it and works but u should remove z from the end. you can read about DateTimeFormatter too

Comment: LocalDateTime from joda time?

Comment: The `Z` in the ISO8601 time stamp means it's UTC time zone, so using local time might give you an incorrect datetime.

Comment: No it is included in JDK 8 or higher

Comment: @Håken Lid. in this case then a Zone id can be created and then using ZonedDateTime..of(LocaleDateTime, Zone Id) but I will check if there is direct way

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is what you should use. And it is even the default format (ISO standard) ;no need for a Datetime Formatter.

Comment: is someone able to provide answer with the example

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Parse the quotes too; use java.time.Instant

Like many others I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

Your string contains double quotes first and last. You can deal with them in two ways:

1. If there’s a way that you can get your string from Bing search without the quotes, do that. Then `Instant.parse()` will parse your string, and you’re done.
2. Otherwise java.time can parse the quotes too.

For parsing the quotes use the following formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter BING_INSTANT_PARSER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendLiteral('"')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)
                .appendLiteral('"')
                .toFormatter();
```

Then parse like this:

```
    String stringFromBing = "\"2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z\"";
    
    Instant instant = BING_INSTANT_PARSER.parse(stringFromBing, Instant::from);
    
    System.out.println("String to parse: " + stringFromBing);
    System.out.println("Result:           " + instant);
```

Output:

> ```
> String to parse: "2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z"
> Result:           2021-09-02T13:16:00Z
> ```

### Which java.time class to use?

Assuming that your string always comes with the `Z` at the end, denoting UTC, `Instant` is the correct class to use. `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` will work too, but I consider them overkill. You don’t want to use `LocalDateTime` since you would then throw away the essential information that the string is in UTC.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are dealing with is called Time Stamp,
there are Duration and INSTANT classes to deal with it.
This page explain it all
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

As @Basil Bourque suggested, we dont need DateTimeFormatter because Instant.parse() by default uses UTC. Also, we can use OffsetDateTime instead of ZonedDateTime (more detailed),

```
String date = "2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z";

Instant timeStamp = Instant.parse(date);

// To get Time or Date," with Instant you must provide time-zone too"
ZonedDateTime dateTimeZone = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timeStamp, ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(dateTimeZone);
System.out.println(dateTimeZone.toLocalDate());// can also be tolocalTime
```

Comment: Your use of `LocalDateTime` here discards the vital information of offset, with nothing gained. I suggest you replace with `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: No need to specify that `DateTimeFormatter` as it is the default.

Comment: Simplify to: `Instant.parse( "2021-09-02T13:16:00.0000000Z" ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate().format( … )`